# Equivalent to "foreign concept"

Tags: word-choice

In my studies I came across "concept" & "conceptually related".
I want to find out the meaning of "concept" and its use.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/concept) shows this example:
***The whole concept of democracy, she claimed, was utterly foreign to the present government.***

Now, I am asking for an equivalent to "foreign" to express that this concept was utterly strange, or unknown to them. Is there a common British used equivalent to "foreign" ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the word from LDOCE 5th edition:

> **concept** - an idea of how something is, or how something should be done

As for the usage of *foreign* in this collocation, there's only one way to substitute it for something else, and that is *alien*:

> **an alien concept** - an idea that is very strange or that does not exist
>
> > In many countries, queuing for a bus is an alien concept.

However, these two words are not always interchangeable, so be careful when you want to use either of them.

Comment: I am searching an expression more "polite and formal". Perhaps "unknown" would be the best choice.....

Comment: @FrankMK, I use "alien concept" regularly when writing about my travel experiences, and it would be perfectly acceptable in a formal context. What makes you think that it may not be polite or formal?

Comment: On all my recent studies, including a lot of business exam books including polite and formal business Englich - also supported by academic material, exercises and definitions, I didn' came across the expression "alien".  What about "unknown" as it is used quite often in an academic context ?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unknown%2C+alien&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunknown%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Calien%3B%2Cc0